# Question ban algorithm formula

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban, ban

Recently we received new question about question ban: [Не разблокируется возможность задавать вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7787/15479)

Member can't ask new questions, the system shows the message:

> We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help
>   Center to learn more.

On MSE I've found this discussion: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/260198)

Our CM answered that algorithm depends on:

1. Number of closed questions.
2. Number of deleted questions.
3. Number of flags.
4. Summary ratings.
5. etc

But, still, the formula is not clear. Could you clarify the exact formula? Without understanding how it works exactly, members don't know what they should do to release the ban. All this "contributing positively to the site in other ways" are kinda abstract phrases, that don't help to those people, actually.

It would be great if you add this information to the help center. On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) page, for example.

Answer (score 14):

It's intentional because, well some folks are going to to work around it the wrong way if they knew. As a mod? I don't know. I don't want to know.

I have a *rough* idea that there's certain things involved - reputation (so someone might resort to voting fraud in an attempt to hit that magic level, and land themselves even deeper in the hole), overall post quality (so closures and deletions). However even as a mod, I don't know the "formula".

On the other hand, I've sometimes tried to help a user fix posts. In my entire time on SU... I've had *one* person pull it off, years ago, before I was a mod even.

So the formula he really needs isn't for the question ban algorithm.

He needs to realise that until he works out what's appropriate for the site *this will keep happening*. He instead needs to try to contribute in other ways - *appropriate* edits and answers can help, but on the whole, it's rare that someone doing that just to get out of a question ban really gets it.

So, the help pages, and a little lurking will *really* help the user rather than knowing "mathematically, what is the bare minimum I can do to get out of the ban."